# lxml etree parse failure (IOError)

Tags: python, parsing, lxml, xml.etree

I am trying to run this program.  It was working fine until today.  Nothing was changed on my end in the code.

```
import lxml.etree
import urlparse
import re

def parse_url(url):
    return lxml.etree.parse(url, lxml.etree.HTMLParser())

urlivv = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=IVV"
docivv = parse_url(urlivv)
```

This is my error message:

`IOError: Error reading file 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=IVV': failed to load external entity "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=IVV"`

There was some documentation on the site about adding `StringIO` to the argument (see below).  But I find it odd I never had to do this before.

```
tree = etree.parse(StringIO(myString))
```

Edit: More complete stack trace.

```
>>> import lxml.etree
>>> tree = lxml.etree.parse('http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=IVV', parser=lxml.etree.HTMLParser())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "src\lxml\lxml.etree.pyx", line 3427, in lxml.etree.parse (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:81100)
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1811, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:117831)
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1837, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:118178)
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1741, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:117090)
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1138, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:111636)
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 595, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:105092)
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 706, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:106800)
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 633, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:105611)
OSError: Error reading file 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=IVV': failed to load external entity "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=IVV"
```

Comment: You say “It was working fine until today. Nothing was changed on my end in the code” but you’re downloading a file from a web server you don’t control. It seems very likely that something changed on the server side and that now you need to update your code to deal with the change.

Comment: @bdesham Thanks for the response.  I'm still newer to this so please bear with me.  The issue seems to pop up on several different websites which are presumably controlled by different web servers (or I'm ignorant here).  Since it failed for the same reason on several URLs I assumed it was a code issue.  Regardless I'm not sure how I would update my code to deal with the change so welcome any feedback.

Comment: Did adding `StringIO` change the result at all? If you try to load that Yahoo URL in a web browser on the same computer that’s running the Python code, are you able to see the webpage?

Comment: @bdesham StringIO is not working.  It is saying "module object is not callable".  But I may be using it wrong.  I tried putting it in the function call and in the function argument itself and both produced the same error.  Yes, I am able to see the webpage in a browser.  Thanks

Comment: Could it be a parser problem? (I added the stack trace.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking for an explanation you can stop reading now. On the other hand, if you seek a remedy then this might be it.

```
>>> page = requests.get('http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=IVV').text
>>> lxml.etree.fromstring(page) #fails
>>> tree = lxml.etree.fromstring(page, parser=lxml.etree.HTMLParser())
>>> tree.xpath('.//table[@class="W(100%)"]')
[<Element table at 0x607dc08>]
```

In short, use `requests` to fetch the page as a string, parse that string with `lxml` and continue as usual.

Edit: Before this code will run you will need `import requests` and `import lxml.etree`.

Comment: Thank you Bill.  The only caveat I would add is one needs to include: import requests

Comment: This would be a much more useful answer—to the OP and others—if you were to explain what the actual problem was and how your code solves it.

Comment: @bdesham: How I wish I could!

Comment: @GC123: True but then I didn't `import` `lxml.etree` either, thinking that these were fairly obvious on SO. Alright, alright, I'll mention them.